# Simulating iOS volume button press in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, volume, simulator

I've been writing a program which performs some function on an iPhone volume button press (like Camera+). There are several stack overflow questions indicating how to do this, but does anyone know how you can test this in the simulator? I would expect there to be some panel I could open where I could click lock, the home button, or volume buttons, but I haven't seen anything. Do I have to test on hardware to test this feature? First time iOS developer. Using Xcode 6.

Comment: Home and Lock are both under the Hardware menu. Volume is probably related to the system volume change, but I can't say I've tested it.

Comment: Did you figure it out how to do it?

Comment: Nope. I had to use hardware to test volume button presses.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem.  System volume doesn't seem to affect it.